# How to call a method from another class using scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval - BEGINNER

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am in Class `A`, i Want to call a method in class `B` how can i do this.

```
NSTimer* timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4 target:[A class] selector:@selector(method2) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

However, the method `method2` is not getting called. How to solve this ?

Comment: You should've instance reference of `B` in your class `A` and then you will set `B` as target of your timer. ie. `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4 target:bInstanceReference selector:@selector(methodOfClassB) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`

Comment: It says undeclared selector `methodOfClassB ` . WHy is this?

Comment: `methodOfClassB` is just a sample for you, you need to change/replace it with your actual method in class `B`.

Comment: You can't do `[A class]` ->  `this is not reference`, you need to create a reference to the class, like `A *obj=[A new];` then pass `obj` to target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A *objectA = [[A alloc] init];
B *objectB = [[B alloc] init];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0f target:objectB selector:@selector(method2) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

You have to imagine it like a method-call. Every 5 seconds whats being executed looks like this:

```
[objectB method2];
```

The actual "objectA" in this case isn't really important as long as its "present" as in it hasn't been deallocated.

Comment: What if `A` is a class of `UIcollectionviewcell`

Comment: Object A doesn't matter. As long as the cell hasn't been deallocated it should work fine. But what exactly are you trying to do? I dont really see a reason why you'd want a repetitive method call started from a UICollectionViewCell

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of a class to send a method to, not the class itself

`A` -> A is the (name of the) class
`A* a` -> a is an instance of class A

```
A* a = [A new];
NSTimer* timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4 
                                                target:a 
                                              selector:@selector(method2) 
                                              userInfo:nil 
                                               repeats:YES];
```